# Arduino CANBUS MCP2515 Extended ID Receive Filter Problem

Tags: c++, filter, arduino, can-bus

I would like to read CANBUS output of a device, but instead of reading every message, I need to filter out all messages **except "0x18DAF938" message**.

I am using Cory J. Fowler's library.

I changed Extended_MaskFilter example code as below but still no success:

```
#include <mcp_can.h>
#include <SPI.h>

long unsigned int rxId;
unsigned char len = 0;
unsigned char rxBuf[8];

MCP_CAN CAN0(53);                          // Set CS to pin 10

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  if(CAN0.begin(MCP_STDEXT, CAN_500KBPS, MCP_8MHZ) == CAN_OK) Serial.print("MCP2515 Init Okay!!\r\n");
  else Serial.print("MCP2515 Init Failed!!\r\n");
  pinMode(2, INPUT);                       // Setting pin 2 for /INT input

  CAN0.init_Mask(0,1,0xFFFFFFFF);                // Init first mask...
  CAN0.init_Filt(0,1,0x18DAF938);                // Init first filter...
                 
  
  Serial.println("MCP2515 Library Mask & Filter Example...");
  CAN0.setMode(MCP_NORMAL);                // Change to normal mode to allow messages to be transmitted
}

void loop()
{
    if(!digitalRead(2))                    // If pin 2 is low, read receive buffer
    {
      CAN0.readMsgBuf(&rxId, &len, rxBuf); // Read data: len = data length, buf = data byte(s)
      Serial.print("ID: ");
      Serial.print(rxId, HEX);
      Serial.print(" Data: ");
      for(int i = 0; i<len; i++)           // Print each byte of the data
      {
        if(rxBuf[i] < 0x10)                // If data byte is less than 0x10, add a leading zero
        {
          Serial.print("0");
        }
        Serial.print(rxBuf[i], HEX);
        Serial.print(" ");
      }
      Serial.println();
    }
}
```

I am using Arduino Mega2560 and NiRen MCP2515 module.

Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: any own debugging attempts? what is your actual question? what is the problem? what do you mean with "no success"?  please read [ask].. if you don't receive, are you sure there is actually something being sent? is your wiring ok?

Comment: I think I found my answer. The actual need is to filter a specific ID to be received. Link attached actually describes what I need. I will try it out and post the result. Thanks! [link]https://github.com/coryjfowler/CAN-Bus_Shield_v1.2/issues/1